Playwright - Electron Application Test automation like an end user
I am trying to launch the electron application using playwright like it described here - https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-electronapplication. But could not get a way to launch the application as a tester who don't have any code related files rather just deployed exe and config file.
I can understand, this launch is used to launch the application from the application code (Dev) which I can't see or use as a tester. I can only see the deployed application exe file and no JS files. If I open the application using the exe, then everything loads or downloads from server, nothing is stored in local machine.
So, trying to understand if there is any approach to open the application and connect that instance or the embedded browser to operate further testing commands.

Note: I have successfully used the approach of opening the application with remoteDebugPort option and accessed the embedded application browser to simulate further operations using MicroFocus UFT pack. Initially, I guessed like - even though the application has an embedded browser still it's a windows application when I open, and I can't access the application browser which is embedded using any web automation frameworks like selenium or so. So, went with UFT.
Recently, I heard like Playwright is supporting the Electron application and trying to understand if it supports from testers perspective.

